# Redirect to custom object tab in lightning

Tags: lightning, tab, flexipages

I have created custom tabs inside an object's flexipage and I wonder if there's a way to redirect via js or apex to this custom tab.
For example I want to be redirected to 'Oferta' tab after doing some custom development.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation), if that solves your use case here?

Comment: @JayantDas Yes, I already checked that and didn't find anything usefull for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `standard__navItemPage` (Navigation Item Page Type) with [`lightning:navigation`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation) here. Refer to the documentation for [`pageReference Types`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm) those are utilized with the component for details. From documentation:

> **Navigation Item Page Type**
>
> A page that displays the content mapped to a CustomTab. Visualforce tabs, Web tabs, Lightning Pages, and Lightning Component tabs are supported.

Your navigation should look like as below:

```
{    
    "type": "standard__navItemPage",
    "attributes": {
        "apiName": "MyCustomTabName" // replace with the API name of your custom tab   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jayant i have used following piece of code i am getting URL doesn't exists error.

Comment: var pageReference =
          {    
            "type": "standard__navItemPage",
            "attributes": {
                "apiName": "Detail" // replace with the API name of your custom tab   
            }
        }; 
     component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
       var navService = component.find("navId");
            var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
            alert(JSON.stringify(pageReference));
            event.preventDefault();
            navService.navigate(pageReference);

Comment: this doesn't work for me