# Navigate to Custom tab on standard object Opportunity

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

Hi I have created a custom tab on the opportunity flexipage named as "Oferta"

as per the req i need to navigate to that tab instead of default summary page of the record as shown in the image
[image]

can someone help me out how to navigate to this custom tab from Lightning Web component on the standard object Opportunity"

below is my code:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.opptyrecordId,
                objectApiName: 'opportunity',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please see this post that has answer. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/243974/redirect-to-custom-object-tab-in-lightning

Answer (score -1):

You can use standard__navItemPage (Navigation Item Page Type) with lightning:navigation here. Refer to the documentation for pageReference Types those are utilized with the component for details. From documentation:

Navigation Item Page Type

A page that displays the content mapped to a CustomTab. Visualforce tabs, Web tabs, Lightning Pages, and Lightning Component tabs are supported.

Your navigation should look like as below:

{
"type": "standard__navItemPage",
"attributes": {
"apiName": "MyCustomTabName" // replace with the API name of your custom tab
}
}